# Mule defining a int value parameter for a Endpoint Config Causes Runtime Error

Tags: mule, mule-studio

I am trying to define port value for a smtp endpoint using util properties. defining a port value using the following mule expression though does not display a error during project compilation, but during execution, the flow generates a exception. Can you advise how to define a intvalue in mule flow.

```
<util:properties id="appconfig"  location="file:///C:/mule-standalone-3.4.0/conf/MuleBus.properties" />
<smtps:outbound-endpoint host="#{appconfig.smtp_host}" port="#[new java.lang.Integer(#{appconfig.smtp_port}).intValue]" to="#{appconfig.smtp_supportlist}" from="#{appconfig.smtp_mailfromuser}" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="SMTP" subject="#[flowVars['mailSubject']]" password="#{appconfig.smtp_mailpassword}" user="#{appconfig.smtp_mailuser}"></smtps:outbound-endpoint>


Caused by: org.mule.api.expression.ExpressionRuntimeException: Execution of the expression "new Integer(465).intValue" failed.
Caused by: [Error: could not access: intValue; in class: java.lang.Integer]
[Near : {... new Integer(465).intValue ....}]
```

kindly advise.

regards
Santosh

Answer (score 0):

No need to do that conversion at all.

```
port="[#{appconfig.smtp_port}]"
```

Try that and see if it works.

Comment: Hi,getting a compilation error, value must be a int value or a mule expression.

Comment: Is appconfig.smtp_port a property? If so use ${appconfig.smtp_port} not #

Comment: i have used util:properties to load this property. using ${appconfig.smtp_port} is not working either :(.